Format xAxis labels in Highchart without Formatter function
i am trying to Format xAxis labels in Highchart without Formatter function.  Formatter function doesn't work when I take the chart configuration separately create a svg from that.
I tried  to apply some inline function but doest give me result.
below mentioned code will give me a integer upto 2 decimal .but in want to do more formatting on the values.
